# Analysis of Hoare's Partioning

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, analysis

I have an assignment to draw a graph and analyze the Hoare's partitioning algorithm and compare theoretical and practical worst-case scenario values. It says that I need a count variable to keep track of critical steps (i.e comparison and swapping). I wrote this code for Hoare's partitioning.

```
public static int partition(Comparable[] a, int left, int right) {
        Comparable pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];
        int i = left - 1, j = right + 1;
        while (true) {
            do {
                i++;
            } while (a[i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);

            do {
                j--;
            } while (a[j].compareTo(pivot) > 0);

            if (i < j) {
                Comparable temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            } else {
                return j;
            }
        }
}
```

Now I am confused about where to add the count variable. I know that count variable will be incremented in if (i < j) line. But do I also need to increment count in both do-while loops to keep track of comparisons?

**So, the updated code will be like this?**

```
public static int partition(Comparable[] a, int left, int right) {
        int count = 0;
        Comparable pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];
        int i = left - 1, j = right + 1;
        while (true) {
            do {
                count++;
                i++;
            } while (a[i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);

            do {
                count++;
                j--;
            } while (a[j].compareTo(pivot) > 0);

            if (i < j) {
                count++;
                Comparable temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            } else {
                return j;
            }
        }
}
```

**Or like this?**

```
public static int partition(Comparable[] a, int left, int right) {
            int count = 0;
            Comparable pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];
            int i = left - 1, j = right + 1;
            while (true) {
                do {
                    i++;
                } while (a[i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);
    
                do {
                    j--;
                } while (a[j].compareTo(pivot) > 0);
    
                if (i < j) {
                    count++;
                    Comparable temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                } else {
                    return j;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You say you need to keep track of comparisons and swapping, then you're asking do you need to keep track of comparisons? Sure, you need.

Comment: I was confused whether while loop is considered as comparison or not.

Comment: `compareTo` in the condition must be accounted